# wget command not working correctly

Tags: github, wget

so I added a setup script to my own repo at this link:
https://github.com/quinnliu/Install_Scripts/blob/master/install_node_and_NPM

but when I type wget  I get a file with the correct name but a whole bunch of .html code instead of the install commands. Anyone have any idea why?

Here is the beginning of the file I get:

```htm
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# githubog: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/githubog#">
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Install_Scripts/install_node_and_NPM at master <C2><B7> quinnliu/Install_Scripts <C2><B7> GitHub</title>
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml" title="GitHub" />
<link rel="fluid-icon" href="https://github.com/fluidicon.png" title="GitHub" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-114.png" />
```

Comment: I figured you're trying to download the setup script with wget by passing it the URL you posted. But it would be much better if you actually included in the question the _exact_ command line you used which produced that html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said, you need the raw link

```sh
$ wget -qO- raw.github.com/quinnliu/Install_Scripts/master/install_node_and_NPM

#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

# Install a special package
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make

# Add a new repository for apt-get to search
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

# Update apt-get's knowledge of which packages are where
$ sudo apt-get update

# Now install nodejs and npm
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to download the [raw file](https://github.com/quinnliu/Install_Scripts/raw/master/install_node_and_NPM).